# How to use default microsoft edge profile/cookies in selenium webdriver? - python

Tags: python, selenium, cookies

```
options  = webdriver.EdgeOptions()
options.add_argument("C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Edge/User Data/Default")
web = webdriver.Edge(EdgeChromiumDriverManager().install(),options= options)
web.get("https://www.instagram.com")
```

Somehow this is not loading the cookies needed to login to instagram. any fix?